# Kubernetes clusterIP does not load balance requests

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, load-balancing

I have a micro service which returns Fibonacci numbers, and I want to have several instances of it in a Kubernetes cluster that is balancing the requests.

This is the configuration:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: fibonacci-deployment
  name: fibonacci-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fibonacci-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fibonacci-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: fibonacci-service:latest
        name: fibonacci-service
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: fibonacci-deployment
  name: fibonacci-deployment
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 8000-8000
    port: 8000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: fibonacci-deployment
  type: ClusterIP
```

And with this command I make accessible the Service:

```sh
> kubectl port-forward svc/fibonacci-deployment 8000:8000
```

This is the script I'm running in several terminal sessions to make the stress test:

```sh
counter=$1
while :
    do
        curl -s http://localhost:8000/fib\?n\=`echo $counter`;
        ((counter++));
done
```

But when I look at the logs of the 3 deployed pods, I only see that requests are being served by only 1 of the pods. Why? What am I missing?

Comment: `kubectl port-forward` always connects to a specific pod, even if you use `service/...` or `deployment/...` syntax; it uses the service's selector to look up a single matching pod and sends all requests to that one pod only.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but how do I achieve the load balancing then?

Comment: You need to launch requests from inside the cluster somehow, or use a NodePort- or LoadBalancer-type service to accept requests from outside.